# Error "UTF-8 Unicode C++ program text, with very long lines" and "ASCII English text, with very long lines"

Tags: linux, encoding, ascii, utf

I have soome files which are commmited from windows to svn. When these files are found by a program running in Linux, it shows the error for a file

*UTF-8 Unicode C++ program text, with very long lines*

and

*and ASCII English text, with very long lines*

for another file.

There are no spaces at the end of the file. I am not sure why it tells "very long lines". All i need is to convert the files to either ASCII English or UTF-8 in linux. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

These are not error messages in themselves, but output from the identification utility `file`. It's not good at recognizing different programming languages, and might think a C++ file is English or Java.

"Very long lines" refers to the fact that the files have lines over 300 characters long.

Both files are already UTF-8 (ASCII is a subset of UTF-8), and therefore don't need conversion (but you might prefer translating the line endings from `\r\n` to `\n` with `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'`.

Comment: i checked the files with errors. All of them have a line which is very long.When that line is deleted, the error is not there. I am checking the property of the file in unix by the command :                                           file "filename". The file is of type 'js'.                          Do we know any encoding which will accept long lines?

Comment: Which program is giving you an error? It sounds like that program has a bug where it's using `file` incorrectly.

Comment: I have a bin file which contains all the necessary data. When the bin is executed using some options (related to my application), at one point ,there is a cp command which will copy some files to a location in my system. Here is where the issue is.

Comment: may be some other part of the program is the problem, when the logs were checked during the bin file extraction. we have the error. Is it possible to convert encoding from UTF-8 Unicode C++ to ASCII English text ? i believe ASCII English text supports long lines

Comment: Neither UTF-8 nor ASCII places any limits on the line length. "C++" just means your file contains a word like "class", which makes `file` think it's C++. "English" means it found a word like "the", so that it's probably English. To convert a file from UTF-8 to ASCII, use `cat file | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii -c > convertedfile`. This gets rid of all non-ascii characters.